# how to delete the last line in file starting with string in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file in the below format

```
AB1234 jhon cell number etc
MD           2         0         8        -1
MD4567 Jhon2 cell number etc
MD           2         0         8        -1
```

I want to find the last line that start with "MD           2"  (not MD as MD is embedded in other data) and delete that line.
so my output should be --

```
AB1234 jhon cell number etc
MD           2         0         8        -1
MD4567 Jhon2 cell number etc
```

I have tried many regular expression in `sed` but it seems it is not working..

```
sed -e '/^MD *2/p' <file Name >
sed '/^(MD           2)/p' <file Name>
```

Comment: i have rolled back my edits as i can make no sense of your data and your question

Comment: @1_CR, FWIW, I think your edits are what the OP meant, except possibly for the multiple spaces between "MD" and "2", etc.

Comment: @shoover, you might be right, thanks. Waiting for the OP to opine ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^MD\s\+2/,${//{x;//p;d};H;$!d;x;s/^[^\n]*\n//}' file
```

This holds a window of lines in the hold space. When it encounters the required pattern, it prints out the current window and starts a new one. At the end of file it prints out all but the first line of the window (as it is the first line that is the required pattern to be deleted).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 2 steps:

1. Find the line number of that line
2. Delete the line using `sed`

For example:

```
n=$(awk '/^MD *2/ { n=NR } END { print n }' filename)
sed "${n}d" filename
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to match exactly `2` in the second column (and not strings that begin with `2`), do two passes:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && $1 == "MD" && $2 == "2"{k=NR} NR!=FNR && FNR!=k' input input
```

Or, if you have access to `tac` and want to make 3 passes on the file:

```
tac input | awk '$1 == "MD" && $2 == "2" && !k{ k=1; next}1' | tac
```

To match when the second column does not exactly equal the string `2` but merely begins with a `2`, replace `$2 == "2"` in the above with `$2 ~ /^2/`

Comment: +1 for the `tac | ... | tac`. Haven't seen that before

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} /^MD *2/ {f=NR} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (f!=i) print a[i]}' file
AB1234 jhon cell number etc
MD           2         0         8        -1
MD4567 Jhon2 cell number etc
```

Store all data in array `a`
Search and find last `MD   2` and store record number in `f`
Then print array `a`, but only if record number is not equal to value in `f`